# Send Address balance to set address/s after a specific time has passed

Tags: solidity, timers

I am very new to the space but looking to setup a contract where;

After a set period of time (defined in the contract), if the balance of the creator is > 0 + gas, send the remaining contents to a set address. It would be great to include tokens and nfts too if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is hardly an automated transfer mechanism possible inherently in solidity. You should allow users to claim (or) try using openzeppelin defender

Comment: Alternatively you could use the ChainLink Keepers : https://chain.link/keepers.
But to slightly rephrase what @SujithSomraaj said : Smart contracts are not autonomous so you must rely on external actions to trigger them.